# Move the dialog box popup in the picture center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating the popup dialog when I've clicked the picture. Now my problem is when the popup dialog shown in the picture below, actually I want to put a popup dialog in the picture center.

Below is my original coding:

```js
function showpopup() {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltiptext");
  let visible = tooltip.style.display;
  if (visible == "none") {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-family: open-sans-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
  outline: none;
}

.tooltip.bottom .arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.tooltip .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #43b02a;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hxa.png" onclick="showpopup()"></img>
<div id="tooltiptext" class="bottom tooltip" style="display: none;">
  <div class="arrow">
  </div>
  LMS short explanation
</div>
```

Actually I want the expected output result like below:

[image: output2]

Hope someone can guide me solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are of a fixed height,  you can simple add a negative margin to 'pull' them up by that number of pixels.

Note the `margin-top -100px;` in the below snippet.

```js
function showpopup() {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltiptext");
  let visible = tooltip.style.display;
  if (visible == "none") {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  margin-top: -100px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-family: open-sans-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
  outline: none;
}

.tooltip.bottom .arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.tooltip .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #43b02a;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hxa.png" onclick="showpopup()"></img>
<div id="tooltiptext" class="bottom tooltip" style="display: none;">
  <div class="arrow">
  </div>
  LMS short explanation
</div>
```